# Try to conver the base64 to image in coldfsuion but its showing it black image

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

Try to convert the base 64 to image in coldfusion but its showing black image.

```
<cfset myImage = "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">

<cfimage action = "write" destination = "test_my66.jpeg" source = "#myImage#" isBase64= "yes" overwrite = "yes">
```

Comment: I think the issue is that you are trying to write a transparent png file as a jpeg. That is why the result image is just black.

Comment: `<cfimage action = "write" destination = "test_my66.png" source = "#myImage#" isBase64= "yes" overwrite = "yes">` This will get you the right image.

Comment: @RRK I tried this but the image showing black only

Comment: Did you try this?

`<cfoutput><cfimage action = "writeToBrowser" source = "#myImage#" isBase64= "yes"></cfoutput>`

Comment: Yes tried and balck image only showing on the browser

Comment: @GowthamSM I've tried your code in my local cf2016. I can able to see some signature behind the image. Which updates version are in your cf2016 ?

Comment: Am using CF2018

Comment: Huh ! you have tagged cf2016 in your question. Please edit & correct it.

Comment: Seems, as you are new user here. Remove your cf10,11,16 tag and add coldfusion & cf2018 tags. And yes, We have the issue in cf2018. And your issue resolved in update4. Please do an update server now. I've post my answer too.

Comment: @Kannan.P Yes Its working on CF18 thanks and But the same issue occured on the CF 11 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gowtham, I've go through your issue in cf2018. Yes we have the issue in cf2018 as black image for **write & writetobrowser** actions. But the issue get resolved in after update the server **Coldfusion 2018 update 4** . Please follow the below step.

**Step 1 :** Go to cfml admin 
**step 2 :** Server update option in nav menu. ( if you are not enable auto notification for update then click check for update button ) 
**step 3:** Please download & update coldfusion 2018 update 4.

The problem get resolved.